# Constructing $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (x,0) \mid x \leq 0 \} \to (-\pi, \pi)$ using polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to construct a well-defined $C^\infty$ function $f(x,y) : \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (x,0) \mid x \leq 0 \} \to (-\pi, \pi)$ via polar coordinates, which cannot be continuously extended to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$.

However, I'm not sure how to even start coming up with ideas for how $f$ should look. I thought that perhaps something involving $\arctan$ might be useful, but I'm not really sure that this counts as using polar coordinates. Also, for example if I set $f(x,y) = 2\arctan(y)$, then I only hit $(\pi, \pi) \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$; I'm not sure how to also hit $(0,0)$.

Comment: Isn't it simply the *angular coordinate* (aka “argument”) that you are looking for? I.e. $f(r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi) = \phi$ with $-\pi < \phi < \pi$.

Comment: Sorry, me previous comment was wrong: Right - I guess the thing I'm confused about is that instead of having a single variable in each entry of your function input, you have two. If I wanted to use $x,y$, due to my domain of definition of $f$, could I use $\mathrm{atan}2$ from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system to define $f(x,y) = \arctan(y/x)$ when $x>0$ and $\arctan(y/x) \pm \pi$ when $x<0$ and $y \geq 0$ or $y <0$, respectively? I guess this is the same as the argument, but maybe this hints at why I can't continuously extend to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus 0$?

Comment: Because at any point $(x_0, 0)$ with $x_0 < 0$ on the negative real axis the function has different limits $\pi$ or $-\pi$, depending on whether you approach $(x_0, 0)$ from “above” or from “below.”

Comment: I see, that makes sense regarding the continuity. If I wanted to write $f$'s definition in terms of $x$ and $y$, would the $\mathrm{atan}2$ thing work? I'm getting a bit confused about this. Let's say $x>0$. Then $\arctan(y/x) = \arctan(\tan(\phi)) = \phi$. But the range of $\arctan(\dots)$ is $-\pi/2 < \dots < \pi/2$. How does this work with our desired range being $(-\pi,\pi)$? I ask about this because it seems to me that it'll be easier to prove $C^\infty$ and the continuity thing rigorously if I write $f$ in terms of $x$ and $y$

Comment: Ahh ok, I guess when you take each case of the definition of $\mathrm{atan}2$ into account, then you get the whole range of $\phi$'s I think.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, but the formulas for $\theta(x, y)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353130/question-about-this-line-integral-whether-it-is-exact) are one way to write down the polar angle. <> I prefer covering the domain by three open half-planes and using both $\arctan$ and $\operatorname{arccot}$ because well-definedness comes from basic trig, after which smoothness is apparent.